# Angular Components inside ngfor card list

Tags: angular

My question is how can I nest a component inside of a card that has been generated with an ngfor loop. I have tried to call it using String Interp but no luck there.

Component.html

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <!--<h1 class="mat-h1">Dashboard</h1>!-->
  <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="350px">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cards | async" [colspan]="card.cols" [rowspan]="card.rows">
      <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
        <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
          <div><app-wager-table></app-wager-table></div>
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
import { WagerTableComponent } from './../wager-table/wager-table.component';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Breakpoints, BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './home-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-dashboard.component.css']
})
export class HomeDashboardComponent {
  /** Based on the screen size, switch from standard to one column per row */
  cards = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset).pipe(
    map(({ matches }) => {
      if (matches) {
        return [
          { title: 'Card 1', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
          { title: 'Card 2', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
          { title: 'Card 3', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
          { title: 'Card 4', cols: 1, rows: 1 }
        ];
      }
      return [
        { title: 'Card 1', data: WagerTableComponent, cols: 2, rows: 1 },
        { title: 'Card 2', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
        { title: 'Card 3', cols: 1, rows: 2 },
        { title: 'Card 4', cols: 1, rows: 1 }
      ];
    })
  );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}
}
```

my goal is to add components inside the cards return.

Comment: What is `mat-grid-tile`? Can you share the HTML template of `mat-grid-tile`? What you are trying to do is the html inside the tags `mat-grid-tile` being parsed by Angular?

Comment: what do you mean the html that is the html mat-grid is a angular material component?

Comment: all i want todo is display a specific component per card thats created

Comment: for example on the return something like this you see on line 2 it says data i want to put that component on card 1